# Android NDK - How to get coordinates from a tap event?

Tags: events, input, android-ndk, coordinates, gesture

I am very new to developing using the Android NDK, and I would like to know, what is the easiest way to get coordinates from a tap event using the Android NDK?  I think I have to include the `input.h` header and use one or more of the AInputEvent methods.  Could anyone help me here?  I am just getting started, so I don't have any code as of other than the base Java and C++ code required for an NDK project.

Comment: NDKDirectory/samples/native-activity has an example of getting input events.

Comment: That could work, although I would prefer to use the JNI.